# Facebook dialog ios cuts down text

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

My facebook dialog cut's down the description field. 
It is supposed to display text like:
Help! Someone has lost their dog, named Fluffy, near 6108 Village Oaks Dr, Ferry Pass, Florida, United States and needs your help to find it. Click this link http://www.fruff.com/832 for Fluffy's lost information.

But the nothing after word 'lost' is displayed, and there is no Show More buttons or anything like this on Facebook. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
    NSString * type = [[petInfo objectForKey:@"type"]lowercaseString];
    NSString * description;



    if([[petInfo objectForKey:@"my_pet"]intValue] == 1){
    description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Help! I have lost my %@, %@, near %@ and I need your help to find it. Click this link %@ for %@'s lost information",type,[petInfo objectForKey:@"name"],[lostInfo objectForKey:@"address"], url,[petInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }
    else{
    description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Help! Someone has lost their %@, named %@, near %@ and needs your help to find it. Click this link %@ for %@'s lost information.              ",type,[petInfo objectForKey:@"name"],[lostInfo objectForKey:@"address"], url,[petInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }


    dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  @"Lost Pet", @"name",
                  @"Help!", @"caption",
                  description, @"description",
                  url, @"link",
                  [petInfo objectForKey:@"picture"], @"picture",
                  nil];


    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:dictionary andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am having the same problem. Freaks me out